# How to view the files loaded in emacs at startup

Tags: emacs

How to view the files that are loaded by the emacs at start up.

I have put the following line in my .emacs file

```
(setq load-path (cons "~/org/org-mode/lisp/" load-path))
(require 'org-install)
```

and expect the file org-install.el to be displayed in the *Messages* buffer,

I have looked at the *Messages* buffer and not able to find any info on the org-install.* file name.

Answer (score 1):

I use "load" rather than "require" in my .emacs because it appends a message to *Messages* regardless of whether is fails or succeeds.

If you are still confused, say ESC ESC : (load "~/org/org-mode/lisp/org-install.el") RET, and tell us what new messages have appeared in *Messages*.

Comment: "Loading /home/lakshbal/org/org-mode/lisp/org-install.el (source)...done
t" is what is printed on the \*message\* buffer